# Listify Theme: Change Searchbar Text

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jobs, searchbar

I have a WordPress [website](http://3.8.56.71/) that is using *wp job manager* plugin and on the top of the website you will see a search bar like this image
[image]

So I just want to change the search bar main text from **All categories** to My own text like *ABC*.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with coding and should be closed.  Also, please read the documentation for your theme before asking us something you could have easily looked up yourself. Good questions on SO show *research effort*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This text is coming from your theme **[Listify](https://astoundify.com/products/listify/)**. As per their [documentation](https://listify.astoundify.com/article/729-various-text-changes), you can change the text as follows:

> For all the text changes below, you must first install the **"Say
>   What"** Plugin.
>
> 1. Install **"[Say What](http://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/)"**
> 2. Visit **"Tools > Text Changes"**
> 3. Then configure the text changes you want to add from the list below.
>
>    - **Any category (on Homepage Search Bar)**
>    - **Original String:** All categories
>    - **Domain:** listify
>    - **Replacement String:** New Text